# SQL/SSRS - How to group data monthly or quarterly

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I am having trouble with the summing of my *LoanAmount* column when I try and group my data.

Below is a sample of my data table. I am logging an entry in this table at the end of every month. I am using this to track the history of a loan. The loan amount for an account gets copied into a new row for each month (it does not change from the first record with this account).

```
AccountNumber   AccountActivationDate   DateTimeLogged  LoanAmount
------------------------------------------------------------------
1               01/01/16                01/31/16        $10.00
1               01/01/16                02/29/16        $10.00
2               02/01/16                02/29/16        $20.00
1               01/01/16                03/31/16        $10.00
2               02/01/16                03/31/16        $20.00
1               01/01/16                03/31/16        $10.00
2               02/01/16                03/31/16        $20.00
3               03/01/16                03/31/16        $30.00
```

When I group my results monthly into an SSRS matrix I end up with something like this (which is the result I am looking for):

```
                                  AccountActivationDate     
                     01/01/16           02/01/16            03/01/16
DateTimeLogged       LoanAmount (SUM)   LoanAmount (SUM)    LoanAmount (SUM)
01/31/16             $10.00     
02/29/16             $10.00             $20.00  
03/31/16             $10.00             $20.00              $30.00
```

However, when I group this data quarterly in an SSRS matrix I run into this:

```
                     AccountActivationDate      
                     Q1 - 2016
DateTimeLogged       LoanAmount (SUM)
Q1 - 2016            $100.00
```

My results for the quarterly grouping give me $100, because it sums up all of these records ($10 x 3 + $20 x 2 + $30 x 1). In reality, I have not giving $100 in loans, but rather $60 ($10 x 1, $20 x 1, $30 x 1).

Is there a way to get the quarterly grouping to only give me the sum of the first LoanAmount and ignore the following ones?

---

**Real Data Example:**

[Monthly Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvLGj.png) | [Quartlery Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8O2Z.png)

The monthly example is working the way I need it two. In the quartlery example, the Amount Financed should be $175,650, not $330,050. The Quarterly Example is summing up the repeating records ($77,200 x 3 + $98,450) instead of ($77,200 + $98,450)

Comment: So the same Account can be activated more than once? but the loan amount of the account is always only the 1 loan amount.  So you have a granularity issue and the Loan Amount is at a higher granularity in your result table making it not a figure you want to aggregate but an attribute of the Loan, where as granularity is actually for ActivationDates related to the loan....So Loan amount part of the 1 and is now being listed as if it is part of the many on a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: Does this have to be done in the report, or ar you able to update the query. If you can update the query then please post the query that supplies data to the report and what version of SQL Server you are using. Once I have that I can hopefully help further.